# View local devices in a virtual machine in remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, remote-desktop

I've this weird situation:
A server machine (CentOS) is running a virtual machine (XP) via VirtualBox.
From my desktop PC (W7) I want to use an USB device.

I've already selected the right options in the local resources panel before starting the remote connection but I can't find my devices on the virtual machine.
[image: The option selected]

Where can I found it?

Comment: The USB device is plugged into which system exactly?

Comment: Sorry, it's plugged into W7 system, the system which is running the remote desktop

Comment: Simplest solution.  You will have to configure VB to see the shared drive.  You won't be able to mount the USB drive I the traditional sense

Comment: I thought about something like `VBoxManage sharedfolder add "VM name" --name "sharename" --hostpath "path"` used for the shared folder but what path should I use? The relative of the W7 machine won't work...am I wrong? Is there a specific command? PS: I will test this solution only on Monday, during weekends I can't access the server.

Comment: When you are doing drive redirection, it is usually done via SMB and a share, located at \\tsclient on the XP machine. I would try to check if you have access to that share from the remote session. Also not, if you are trying to log in as a non-administrator, I am not sure what your permissions are.